# eureka is not able to register the client applications when running the docker containers, though in local , system is working as expected

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker, https, netflix-eureka

I am working on a microservice application and I have following services currently:

1. discovery (eureka server)
2. authentication service(Eureka client).

I am running all the services on HTTPS , for the same purpose I have created the keystore and cer file for each service and importing the cer in the keystore of each service.

**Below is the details How I am creating the keystore and cer file:**

*To create the keystore for the discovery :*

```
keytool -genkey -alias eureka-app -keyalg RSA -storetype PKCS12 -keystore eureka.p12 -ext SAN=dns:eureka.com,dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1,ip:192.168.5.67
```

*To Create the keystore for the authenticationservice:*

```
keytool -genkey -alias authservice-app -keyalg RSA -storetype PKCS12 -keystore authservice.p12 -ext SAN=dns:auth.com,dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1,ip:192.168.5.67
```

*To Create the cer file for discovery:*

```
keytool -export -alias eureka-app -file eureka.cer -keystore eureka.p12
```

*To Create the cer file for authenticationservice:*

`keytool -export -alias authservice-app -file authservice.cer -keystore` authservice.p12

*Then exporting the certificates I used below commands:*

```
keytool -import -alias authservice-app -file authservice.cer -keystore eureka.p12

keytool -import -alias eureka-app -file eureka.cer -keystore authservice.p12
```

Below is the application.yml configuration for discovery:

```
spring:
   application:
      name: ${EUREKA_APPLICATION_NAME:estri-eureka}
server:
   port: ${SERVER_PORT:8761}
   ssl:
      enabled: true
      key-store: classpath:eureka.p12
      key-store-password: eurekaserver
      trust-store: classpath:eureka.p12
      trust-store-password: eurekaserver
      key-alias: eureka-app
eureka:
   client:
      register-with-eureka: ${BOOL_REGISTER:false}
      fetchRegistry: ${BOOL_FETCH:false}
      enabled: true
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka/
   instance:
      hostname: ${HOST_NAME:localhost}
      secure-port-enabled: true
      health-check-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.secure-port}/ctx/health
      status-page-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.secure-port}/ctx/info
      home-page-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.secure-port}/ctx
   server:
      enable-self-preservation: ${SELF_PRESERVATION:false}
```

*Below is the application.yml configuration for authservice:*

```
eureka:
   instance:
      nonSecurePortEnabled: false
      securePortEnabled: true
      securePort: ${server.port}
      statusPageUrl: https://${HOST_NAME:localhost}:${server.port}/actuator/info
      healthCheckUrl: https://${HOST_NAME:localhost}:${server.port}/actuator/health
      homePageUrl: https://${HOST_NAME:localhost}:${server.port}/home
      hostname: ${HOST_NAME:localhost}
      #preferIpAddress: true
   client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/}
      registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
      heartbeat-executor-thread-pool-size: 5
      eureka-service-url-poll-interval-seconds: 10
```

**Note-** I am using the hostname to register the services into the eureka instead of Ip address. with the above mentioned configurations I am able to run the system as expected on my local system.

But when I am creating the containers for the service and trying to run the application I am getting error

**Below are the configurations**

*Dockerfile for authservice*

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8081
ENV APP_HOME /authservice
ADD target/*.jar authservice.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","authservice.jar"]
```

*Dockerfile for discovery*

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8761
ENV APP_HOME /discovery
ADD target/*.jar discovery.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","discovery.jar"]
```

**Docker-Compose file as below**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   discovery:
      image: discovery
      ports:
        - 8761:8761
      networks:
        - estri_gateway_network
      environment:
        EUREKA_APPLICATION_NAME: eureka
        HOST_NAME: localhost
   authservice:
      image: authservice
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      networks:
        - estri_gateway_network
      deploy:
         replicas: 1
         #endpoint-mode: dnsrr
      environment:
        HOST_NAME: localhost



networks:
  estri_gateway_network:
```

**Now when I run the above docker compose file I get the below error:**

```
2020-01-02 13:10:02.591 ERROR [authservice,,,] [authservice,,,] 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='https://localhost:8761/eureka/}
authservice_1  |
authservice_1  | com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1069)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:983)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1497)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1464)
authservice_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
authservice_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
authservice_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
authservice_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
authservice_1  |        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
authservice_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
authservice_1  |        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
authservice_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.SSLSocketFactoryAdapter.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactoryAdapter.java:59)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
authservice_1  |        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
authservice_1  |        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
authservice_1  |        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers cannot communicate with other containers using `localhost`, but they can communicate using their service name and the service name of your eureka server is `discovery` on the Docker compose file.

You already have a environment variable named as `EUREKA_URI` to set full URL of the eureka server on the application.yml of authservice (check `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` variable).

```
   authservice:
      image: authservice
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      networks:
        - estri_gateway_network
      deploy:
         replicas: 1
         #endpoint-mode: dnsrr
      environment:
        HOST_NAME: authservice
        EUREKA_URI: https://discovery:8761/eureka
```

It is also better to set `HOST_NAME` as the docker service name. So that authservice can tell eureka server its hostname working on the Docker network.